# Embedded Options in a Custom Metabox

Tags: customization, metabox

I am successfully able to create a number of custom metaboxes. There are a number of tutorials online that help with that.

My question is how to include embedded options in a custom metabox?

So, what are embedded options? Well, if you take the "Publish Post" metabox, for example, this is what you will see:

[image]

Notice that if you click on the "Edit" link that is circled in red in the image above, this is what you will end up with:

[image]

Those are what I call embedded options (I do not know the term for them, so I came up with that name). And what I want to do is something similar. I know I can achieve that with JavaScript/AJAX, but I like to know if there are already pre-written methods in WordPress and a process to follow for creating that part of the metabox so that I do not re-invent the wheel.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long investigation, it turned out that there isn't any WordPress method that generates that information via methods/functions. That functionality should be built manually. For example, for the "publish post" metabox which contains the required functionality above, the code is listed here

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php#L22